# Proposition $1.3$ in Bondy & Murty's Graph Theory.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G[X,Y]$ be a bipartite graph, with no isolated vertices, and $d(x) \ge d(y)$, $\forall$ $xy \in E$ (where $E$ denotes the set of edges in $G$). Then: $|X| \le |Y|$, with equality iff $d(x) = d(y), \forall \ xy \in E$.

I understand the proof of the first part, but the proof of the second isn't very clear.

It's clear that when $d(x) = d(y)$, we have $|X| = |Y|$. However, if $|X| = |Y|$, I don't understand why need it follow that $d(x) = d(y), \forall \ xy \in E$.

The proof of the inequality is:

$$|X| = \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y, \\ xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(x)} = \sum_{x \in X, \\ y \in Y} \sum_{xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(x)} \le \sum_{x \in X, \\ y \in Y}\sum_{xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(y)} = \ldots = |Y|$$

Equality between $|X|$ and $|Y|$ gives:

$$ \sum_{x \in X, \\ y \in Y} \sum_{xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(x)} =  \sum_{x \in X, \\ y \in Y}\sum_{xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(y)}$$

Apparently, this is what should give the required result, but I don't understand how.

Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'll assume that "$G\left[X,Y\right]$ is a bipartite graph" means "$G$ is a bipartite graph, and $X$ and $Y$ are its two shores (or what else you call the two parts into which the vertex set of a bipartite graph is partitioned)", and that $d\left(v\right)$ means the degree of a vertex $v$.

Comment: Anyway, if $d\left(x\right) = d\left(y\right)$ for each $xy \in E$, then $d\left(x\right) \geq d\left(y\right)$ for each $xy \in E$, and thus the first part of the claim yields $\left|X\right| \leq \left|Y\right|$. But the same argument, with $X$ and $Y$ switched, yields $\left|Y\right| \leq \left|X\right|$ (since the equality $d\left(x\right) = d\left(y\right)$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$). Combining, you get $\left|X\right| = \left|Y\right|$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: But that is the trivial part. I'm asking about $|X| = |Y| \implies d(x)=d(y), \forall \ x,y$

Comment: Ah! Sorry for the misunderstanding. If a sum of several inequalities becomes an equality, then every of the inequalities that have been summed must be an equality. Thus, in your case, from $\left|X\right| = \left|Y\right|$, we conclude that $\dfrac{1}{d\left(x\right)} = \dfrac{1}{d\left(y\right)}$ for every $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ satisfying $xy \in E$. In other words, $d\left(x\right) = d\left(y\right)$ whenever $xy \in E$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to see it is to note first that since $d(x)\ge d(y)$ for each $xy\in E$, we must have $\frac1{d(x)}\le\frac1{d(y)}$ for each $xy\in E$. Thus,

$$\sum_{x\in X,y\in Y,xy\in E}\left(\frac1{d(y)}-\frac1{d(x)}\right)$$

is a sum of non-negative terms, and as such is (a) non-negative, and (b) zero if and only if each term $\frac1{d(y)}-\frac1{d(x)}$ is zero. But

$$\sum_{x\in X,y\in Y,xy\in E}\left(\frac1{d(y)}-\frac1{d(x)}\right)=\sum_{x\in X,y\in Y,xy\in E}\frac1{d(y)}-\sum_{x\in X,y\in Y,xy\in E}\frac1{d(x)}\;,\tag{1}$$

and we know that the righthand side of $(1)$ is $0$, so each term $\frac1{d(y)}-\frac1{d(x)}$ of the lefthand side of $(1)$ must be $0$, and hence $d(x)=d(y)$ for each $xy\in E$.